# Accessing Twitter streaming API - authentication does not work in R

Tags: r, twitter

I am using the following code to connect to Twitter streaming API to download tweets

```
#install.packages("streamR")
#install.packages("ROAuth")

library(ROAuth)
library(streamR)

#create your OAuth credential
credential <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey='**CONSUMER KEY**',
                         consumerSecret='**CONSUMER SECRETY KEY**',
                         requestURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
                         accessURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
                         authURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')

#authentication process
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
credential$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

It throws this error:

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

This code was perfectly working a couple of years ago, can someone please guide me, what do I need to change?

P.S. I am working latest versions of R and R studio.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that has changed on the Twitter side in “a couple of years” is that we now enforce TLS 1.2 for connections. The error you’re seeing is an SSL/TLS issue. I’m not sure how to resolve that with Rstudio but I’d recommend looking at the libraries and settings related to that area.